# Why is using a regex pre-compiled with qr slower than using a constant regex?

Tags: perl

I just saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43009501/869025) about optimizing a particular regular expression in Perl. I wondered about how many matches my machine could do, so I tried the following simple benchmark:

- case 1 - using a regex pre-compiled with `qr`
- case 2 - plain `/regex/` match

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use Benchmark qw(:all);

my $str = "SDZ";
my $qr = qr/S?T?K?P?W?H?R?A?O?\*?E?U?F?R?P?B?L?G?T?S?D?Z?/;

say "match [$&]" if( $str =~ $qr );

my $res = timethese(-10, {
    stdrx => sub { $str =~ /S?T?K?P?W?H?R?A?O?\*?E?U?F?R?P?B?L?G?T?S?D?Z?/ },
    qr_rx => sub { $str =~ $qr },
});

cmpthese $res;
```

To my surprise, it gave the following result:

```
match [SDZ]
Benchmark: running qr_rx, stdrx for at least 10 CPU seconds...
     qr_rx: 10 wallclock secs ( 9.99 usr +  0.01 sys = 10.00 CPU) @ 1089794.90/s (n=10897949)
     stdrx: 11 wallclock secs (10.58 usr +  0.04 sys = 10.62 CPU) @ 1651340.11/s (n=17537232)
           Rate qr_rx stdrx
qr_rx 1089795/s    --  -34%
stdrx 1651340/s   52%    --
```

i.e. the plain `$str =~ /regex/` is about 50% faster than using `$str =~ qr`. I expected the opposite result.

Am I doing something wrong? Why am I getting this result?

### EDIT:

Just [downloaded](https://www.google.sk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjDmaKxoPLSAhVFnBoKHY6DBY0QFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fshihyu%2FRegular_Expressions%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2FOreilly.Mastering.Regular.Expressions.3rd.Aug.2006.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEu1ggWvWg_NqBsjcfr3GdAIGLGBg&sig2=9obsF_m4s_NPgouMn3lWog) the cited book, I have much to learn :). But, the cited book also says:

> If a regex literal has no variable interpolation, Perl knows that the regex can’t change from use to use, so after the regex is compiled once, that compiled form is saved (“cached”) for use whenever execution again reaches the same code. The regex is examined and compiled just once, no matter how often it’s used during the program’s execution.

So, in the above both regexes are *literal* without variable interpolation. So, the "precompiled" regex **should be same fast as the plain one**. In the example, it is slower by 50%.

Ikegami explained why the `$str =~ $qr` is slower. (and honestly the "slower" isn't the right term, because we talking about few microseconds... :))

BUT the perl docs says:

> Precompilation of the **pattern** into an internal representation at
>   the moment of qr() avoids the need to recompile the pattern every time
>   a match /$pat/ is attempted.

From the point of view of an ordinary perl user ("not some high level perl monk"), this means: *precompile your pattern - it will be faster*, but the truth is - it helps only if the regex contains some "non-static" parts...

Honestly, me still not understand this fully - but got a book and going to learn. :) Maybe one sentence more in the docs - could help beginners do not misunderstand the `qr` when they starting to learn.

Thank you all!

Comment: Why did you expect `qr` to be faster? Also, does anything change if you remove `$&` from your program?

Comment: @melpomene because the doc says: _Precompilation of the pattern into an internal representation at the moment of qr() avoids the need to recompile the pattern every time a match /$pat/ is attempted._ Me understand this as: the compilation needs more processing, so it must be slower. (looks like thats not valid). (nothing changes by removing the `$&`)

Comment: But you don't have `/$pat/` in your code. All your regexes are static, with no variable interpolation. The only thing `qr` gives you here is a level of indirection because at the point of the match it has to fetch the contents of `$qr` and test whether it's a regex object or a string, whereas `=~ /.../` stores the regex as part of the match op.

Comment: Hi there. I started the thread you referenced. The reason I used a named regex reference with `qr` is because the regex is used in several places in the program. It helps avoid typos as well as confusion with a few other similar-looking regexes to see `$valid_steno` instead of another long regex, performance questions aside.

Comment: Re "*In the example, it is slower by 50%.*", Not quite. It's slower by a constant amount.

Comment: Re "*but the truth is - it helps only if the regex contains some "non-static" parts...*", Or more precisely, if you don't already have a pre-compiled regex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regex patterns are compiled at compile-time if they don't interpolate. Neither the regex in the `qr//` operator nor the one in match operator in `stdrx` interpolate, so both are compiled at compile-time.

The extra 30μs spent in the `qr_rx` test is spent "compiling" the third regex: The one in the match operator in `qr_rx`. Don't forget that `$_ =~ $re` is short for `$_ =~ m/$re/`. Now, no compilation actually occurs when the whole pattern consists of an interpolated pre-compiled regex because that case is handled specially, but it apparently still takes a bit of time to coax the match op into using the pre-compiled regex. (Maybe it needs to clone it?)

Comment: Thanks for this insight. But isn't this kind of weird? It seems from this it is not possible to use a precompiled regex (at runtime) in a match operation without compiling the regex again.  It means it can never be faster to use a compiled a regex?

Comment: As usually - nice, detailed and helpful answer. Anyway, the `qr` should be more/better documented. Me asked my collegauoes too, they understands the doc like me, :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland 1) I haven't bothered stepping through the code, but I'm guessing it's not a "full" re-compilation; there's still a regcomp opcode for each loop iteration, but it only does trivial work like cloning the pre-compiled regex. 2) `qr` can't be faster than a constant regex. It *can* be faster when you interpolate variables into your pattern (although not always; `/$foo/` inside a loop is only compiled once and cached if `$foo` never changes, but there's a string comparison on each iteration; if that is faster than the overhead from `qr`, then `qr` still loses. *(continued)*

Comment: @HåkonHægland See "The internal mechanics of preparing a regex" on page 350 of [Mastering Regular Expressions](https://books.google.com/books?id=sshKXlr32-AC&pg=PA350&lpg=PA350&dq=perl+regex+variable+cache&source=bl&ots=daTW0Q4fMg&sig=tw27iHEkor0cKcuz7I4IfxNWXjA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5pJv1yvHSAhUP2mMKHb9CDP4Q6AEINzAF#v=onepage&q=perl%20regex%20variable%20cache&f=false) (but ignore the part about the `/o` modifier, which is out-dated). You can also benchmark this yourself: compare `'foo' =~ /$foo/` to `$qr = qr/$foo/; 'foo' =~ $qr` when `$foo` is 100 vs. 1 million characters long.

Comment: @cajwine `qr` can help when you use variables in your pattern. There's no reason to use it for a constant regex with no modifiers like in your question.

Comment: All you did was add a layer of indirection. Whether the patterns in `@res` are compiled or not will make a difference here: `for (...) { for my $re (@res) { ... /$re/ ... } }`.